# tx_dam with TYPO3 6.1

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, dam

I'm benchmarking TYPO3 6.1 and I'm trying to install and make DAM extension working on it.
I'm experiencing issues after installation.

I can see the media folder in the pages tree. But when I want to use the "media>file" module, I get the error "The requested path do not exists." with no pages tree.
The base path is "fileadmin/" and the folder exists.

[image: My error in the backend]

If someone has an idea, it's welcome.

See ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dam doesnt work anymore with 6.x, use https://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Extensions/media.git which is currently under heavy development

Comment: To give it a try, download the bootstrap package from http://get.typo3.org/bootstrap which has EXT:media preinstalled and preconfigured.

Comment: Thanks but I used it from scratch :)